# How to properly change the camera view to move forward and backward into a scene in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I want to make it such that I can move around in the following manner in three.js by moving the perspectivecamera:

1. "hit a key or button to move the camera forward into the direction im looking at"
2. "hit a key or button to move the camera downward below the direction im looking at"
3. "hit a key or button to pitch the camera such that the "fov" is of a different value
4. "hit keys or buttons to pitch the camera such that i am rotating as if pivoted at the place the camera is to be able to see whats left and right of me

The following is my current code. Based on what I am seeing, it appears that PerspectiveCamera from the docs does not appear to have any methods like "setFov" or anything like that, simply "camera.fov = " does not appear to have any effect like the meshes after the camera has been initialized. So how would I properly be able to do the above?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 01.03 - Materials and light</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Stats-output">
</div>
<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    $(function () {

        var stats = initStats();

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setClearColorHex(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

        // create the ground plane
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,20,1,1);
        var planeMaterial =    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
        plane.receiveShadow  = true;

        // rotate and position the plane
        plane.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        plane.position.x=15
        plane.position.y=0
        plane.position.z=0

        // add the plane to the scene
        scene.add(plane);

        // create a cube
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4,4,4);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.castShadow = true;

        // position the cube
        cube.position.x=-4;
        cube.position.y=3;
        cube.position.z=0;

        // add the cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);

        var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4,20,20);
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x7777ff});
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry,sphereMaterial);

        // position the sphere
        sphere.position.x=20;
        sphere.position.y=0;
        sphere.position.z=2;
        sphere.castShadow=true;

        // add the sphere to the scene
        scene.add(sphere);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add subtle ambient lighting
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        // add spotlight for the shadows
        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
        spotLight.position.set( -40, 60, -10 );
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add( spotLight );

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        $("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);

        // call the render function
        var step=0;
        render();

        function render() {
            stats.update();
            // rotate the cube around its axes
            cube.rotation.x += 0.02;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
            cube.rotation.z += 0.02;

            // bounce the sphere up and down
            step+=0.04;
            sphere.position.x = 20+( 10*(Math.cos(step)));
            sphere.position.y = 2 +( 10*Math.abs(Math.sin(step)));

            // render using requestAnimationFrame
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function initStats() {

            var stats = new Stats();

            stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

            // Align top-left
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

            $("#Stats-output").append( stats.domElement );

            return stats;
        }
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you simply need to understand the components of the camera's matrix to realize what you want. The three.js "camera" is a 4x4 matrix of the classic linear algebra type. 

`4x4 matrix = [a b c d
              e f g h
              i j k l
              n m o p]`

The 3x3 inner matrix is literally the orientation of your camera:

`camera orientation = [a b c
                      e f g
                      i j k]`
 
Meaning the vector { a, b, c } is the direction vector pointing to the camera's right, from the camera's pov. The vector { e, f, g } is the direction vector pointing up, from the camera's point of view. And the vector { i, j, k } is the director vector pointing in the direction the camera is facing.

Together these 3 vectors compose the orientation of the camera.

They can be further envisioned by holding your left hand in front of you like this: 
[image: left handed rotation picture]
Each finger is pointing in the positive direction of the camera's pov, and they likewise equal the rotation factors necessary to orient the camera.

And the other, non-rotation components { n, m, o } is the x, y, z position of the camera.

To move in the direction of the camera, add the vector { i, j, k } to { n, m, o }.

To move to the right, from the camera's pov, add the vector { a, b, c } to { n, m, o }.

To move up, from the camera's pov, add the vector { e, f, g } to { n, m, o }.

And, of course, to move in the opposite directions add the negatives of those orientation vectors.