# Move camera backwards and forwards in Three js

Tags: vector, camera, three.js

How would you move a camera backwards and forwards from a fixed point along the trajectory that it is facing?

I know there are several control scripts that do this but I need to do something custom and I'm not able to break down their code to figure how to isolate the above behaviour.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661571/how-to-properly-change-the-camera-view-to-move-forward-and-backward-into-a-scene) which I think addresses the question and have come up with this code:

```
cameraPosition = camera.position
cameraRotation = new THREE.Vector3(camera.rotation._x, camera.rotation._y, camera.rotation._z)
newCamera = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(cameraPosition, cameraRotation)
camera.position.set(newCamera.x, newCamera.y, newCamera.z)
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

But this seems to move the camera in a circle rather than backwards and forwards.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: to move camera backwards or forwards you just need to change z component of the camera position, adding to it some delta vector.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052621/moving-the-camera-in-the-direction-its-facing-with-threejs/38057216#38057216

Comment: Again, read the link I posted.

Comment: @WestLangley You're right. Sorry I didn't check that earlier. I assumed that `camera.translateZ( x )` would be the same as `camera.position.z += x;`. But I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To move the camera forward or backward the direction it is facing, use

```
camera.translateZ( - distance );
```

or

```
camera.translateZ( distance );
```

three.js r.78

Comment: and not surprisingly `camera.translateX` and `camera.translateY` do camera relative translations sideways and up and down respectively.

Comment: But this makes the camera also go downwards instead of only forward.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you do it by updating the `camera.position.z`. Use the `W`=forward, `S`=backward

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add(camera);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    document.body.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onKeyDown(){
switch( event.keyCode ) {
   case 83: // up
   camera.position.z += 50;
   break;
   case 87: // down
   camera.position.z -= 50;
   break;
}
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I guess I should have been more specific though... In my scene the camera has x, y, & z position's set and is pointing at the centre of the scene. I was hoping to move the camera along the trajectory it was facing. I've modified your code above to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/a9rhtLnk/ - Now the camera moves over the cube, but I was trying to make it move *into* the cube

Comment: `camera.lookAt( mesh.position );` will look into the cube.