# ThreeJS: How to move the camera to the left or right independent of its rotation?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a ThreeJS set up where the camera can move through a 3D world and while moving it will change its `lookAt` multiple times. So let's assume that `camera.getWorldDirection()` will always be more or less random.

Now I need the camera to move exactly left / right / up / down relative to `camera.getWorldDirection()`.
You **can't** just use something like `camera.position.x += 1` because that only applies for a world direction of `Vector3(0, 0, -1)`. If the world direction changes to e.g. `(1, -1, 0)`, moving the camera to the right does require changes in the X and the Z axis.

I had a look at quaternions and 4D matrices but I can't get my monkeybrain around them. Would be really nice if someone could help me out.

Here is a demo: https://normanwink.com/demo/room/

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341191/1461008

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the hint but unfortunately it won't work due to the rotation of the camera. E.g. if I turn my camera 90 degrees clockwise, moving "forward" along Z will result in a movement to the left, relative to the cameras perspective.

Comment: How does the solution in the link I posted above differ from the solution in the link you posted in your answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052621/moving-the-camera-in-the-direction-its-facing-with-threejs?noredirect=1&lq=1) in a non-accepted answer.

You gotta use `camera.translateX()` and similar functions to transform its local position. That way you can always manipulate `camera.position` to move it around and have the `translate` functions to add offsets relative to the cameras viewing angle.